# Which is correct: "first ever loss" or "first loss ever"

Tags: word-order

Consider the following two phrases

> 1. Microsoft reports first quarterly loss *ever*
> 2. Microsoft reports first *ever* quarterly loss

Which of the them is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is right and ok.

In both headlines, "ever" is used as [an adverb with the meaning of "at any time.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ever)"

The first, "Microsoft reports first quarterly loss *ever*," is the same as:

> Microsoft reports the first quarterly loss they *have ever had*.

It emphasizes the meaning that something has never happened before.

In the second, "Microsoft reports *first ever* quarterly loss," the adverb "ever" is used as part of a longer structure. Similar to:

```
the + superlative + ever
```

> Ex. *The largest ever* theme park

It is used to emphasize the comparison being made with the past.

In any case, the difference is minimal and they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the word *ever* and the phrase will have exactly the same meaning. Tacking "ever" onto the end is akin to tacking "for the first time" onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.
Check
[First Loss Ever](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/business/breaking-news/microsoft-reports-first-loss/story-e6frg90f-1226430529176),
[First Ever Loss](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=first+ever+loss&oq=first+ever+loss&gs_l=hp.3..0i5j0i5i30l3j0i5.633.8012.1.12382.15.12.0.3.3.0.358.2953.2-11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.2SAhpP9z5No&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=52b8d6ef2b866f83&biw=1366&bih=602)
for reference